# Feedback link on Careers is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

The [checkout page](https://careers.stackoverflow.com/checkout/search) (need to be logged into Careers) has a feedback link on the left hand side, but clicking it doesn't do anything.

It still sends the request to the server, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for pointing it out, that should be fixed now -- the SSL on that page was breaking the popup.